# SQL Server count orders within dates per customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the following data:

- List all customers who have ordered twice or more in the last 12 months
- List all customers who have ordered just once in last 12 months
- List any customers who do not fit in the criteria above

I'm using SQL Server 11.0.

I have the following tables:

**dbo.[Order]**:

```
CustomerID
OrderID
```

**dbo.Customer**:

```
BusinessName
Postcode
```

**dbo.AccountCallbacks**:

```
UserId
NotInterestedReasonID
```

I need a count of all orders from dbo.[Order] where the last record in dbo.AccountCallbacks had the UserID of '6EAE3206-519E-4DE7-B10B-6F2476D7D20F' and a null NotInterestedReasonID between each of the date ranges above and then for everything else.

I'm not sure what other information to give, this is what I have come up with currently, but feel I'm going about it in a peculiar fashion!

```
SELECT
    Customer.CustomerID,
    BusinessName,
    Postcode,
    NumOrders
FROM  
    Customer
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CustomerID,
         COUNT(OrderID) AS NumOrders
     FROM 
         dbo.[Order]
     WHERE 
         UserId = '6EAE3206-519E-4DE7-B10B-6F2476D7D20F'
         AND NOT (PaymentDate IS NULL)
         AND OrderDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
     GROUP BY 
         CustomerID) AS payingCustomers ON Customer.CustomerID = payingCustomers.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CustomerID,
         MAX(CallbackDate) AS LastCallbackDate
     FROM 
         dbo.AccountCallBacks
     WHERE 
         NotInterestedReasonID IS NULL
     GROUP BY 
         CustomerID) AS otherCustomers ON Customer.CustomerID = otherCustomers.CustomerID
ORDER BY 
    NumOrders DESC
```

As you may have guessed, SQL isn't my strongest suit! I really hope I've given the needed info, if not, let me know.

Example Data:

**AccountCallbacks:**

```
CallbackID  UserID  CustomerID  Created CallbackDate    Enabled CallbackTimeID  NotInterestedReasonID
16  695624B5-90E0-45C0-AFCF-07C7A275BE6E    504 2011-02-01 10:40:37.183 2015-10-08  1   3   1
17  695624B5-90E0-45C0-AFCF-07C7A275BE6E    505 2011-02-01 10:40:37.220 2011-11-01  0   3   NULL
18  2B37842F-33AF-4777-9FC7-3D4F648F5D8F    506 2011-02-01 10:40:37.263 2012-08-20  0   1   NULL
19  2B37842F-33AF-4777-9FC7-3D4F648F5D8F    508 2011-02-01 10:40:37.300 2012-07-20  0   1   NULL
20  2B37842F-33AF-4777-9FC7-3D4F648F5D8F    509 2011-02-01 10:40:37.340 2014-02-10  0   1   NULL
```

**Order:**

```
OrderID CustomerID  UserID  OrderDate   PaymentTypeID   PaymentStatusID PaymentDate TransactionRef  PurchaseOrderNumber
44523   4199    695624B5-90E0-45C0-AFCF-07C7A275BE6E    2016-10-11 16:54:01.350 1   2   2016-10-11 16:57:13.000 011194  
44522   3748    695624B5-90E0-45C0-AFCF-07C7A275BE6E    2016-10-11 16:13:00.290 1   2   2016-10-11 16:13:57.000 011486  
44521   1812    2B37842F-33AF-4777-9FC7-3D4F648F5D8F    2016-10-11 16:08:16.923 1   2   2016-10-11 16:09:33.000 082663
```

**Customer:**

```
CustomerID  BusinessName    Postcode
502 Company 1   BP3 6UK
503 Company Name    BP3 6BK
504 Company ABC SS13 1LS
```

Expected output : (this would be a different set of data depending on which 'report' it is as stated above)

```
CustomerID  BusinessName    Postcode
799 Company2 LTD    YO17 6YA    
5586    Company3 Plc    EH3 9DJ 
5638    MR A ENG LTD    EP4 1PL 
6707    DUSTO Ltd   NE22 7LB
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Added example data from each table and the expected output. thanks

Comment: @MichaelEaton I'll update my answer if those don't work and if you can explain the third question for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**List all customers who have ordered twice or more in the last 12 months**

```
SELECT COUNT(o.OrderID), o.CustomerID
FROM Order o 
WHERE o.UserID = '6EAE3206-519E-4DE7-B10B-6F2476D7D20F'
    AND o.OrderDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(o.OrderID) > 2
```

**List all customers who have ordered just once in last 12 months**

```
SELECT COUNT(o.OrderID), o.CustomerID
FROM Order o 
WHERE o.UserID = '6EAE3206-519E-4DE7-B10B-6F2476D7D20F'
    AND o.OrderDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(o.OrderID) = 1
```

I'm a little confused on the problem. You want all of the customers who "don't fit in the criteria." What criteria?

Comment: "Don't fit criteria above" would be 0 orders during date range, is my guess.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, that's all you'd have to do. Does this solution work for you?

Comment: @Gary Just realized that you weren't the OP, ha. I thought that "0 orders during date range" might be what he meant, but wasn't sure.